# Safer way to use importlib.import_module to avoid Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

After the `import_module` statement below fails, the mere presence of a second thread causes a Segmentation fault when the thread finishes. No segfault when there is only one thread.

Is there a safer way to conditionally import a module which may error depending on the system environment? Maybe a way to 'clear' the C level error somehow or revert to the state prior to having called `import_module`

I am not lookin to solve the problem causing the Segfault. I am interested in preventing this from crashing my application.

Also out of curiosity, why does this only happen when there is a second thread?.

```
# example of issue.
import sys
import time
import threading
import importlib

def main():
    try:
        cv2 = importlib.import_module('cv2')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

################################################################################
# Segmentation fault only occurs when a second thread is created.
# if this section is commented out no Segfault occurs
    def fn():
        for i in range(0, 3):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(str(i))

    t = threading.Thread(target=fn, daemon=True)
    t.start()

    print("waiting for thread.")
    t.join()
    print("Thread finished.") # <--- Never called. Segafaults before this.

################################################################################

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here is the output of a gdb backtrace. The problem is caused by the absence of a shared library which `cv2` requires

`libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

```
Thread 2 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb666d460 (LWP 19304)]
0xb6fdab80 in elf_machine_rel (skip_ifunc=0, reloc_addr_arg=0xb2df4ff0, version=0x20, sym=0xb2de4170, reloc=0xb2de4340, map=0x4c3518)
    at ../sysdeps/arm/dl-machine.h:394
394     ../sysdeps/arm/dl-machine.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb6fdab80 in elf_machine_rel (skip_ifunc=0, reloc_addr_arg=0xb2df4ff0, version=0x20, sym=0xb2de4170, reloc=0xb2de4340, map=0x4c3518)
    at ../sysdeps/arm/dl-machine.h:394
#1  elf_dynamic_do_Rel (skip_ifunc=0, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, 
    map=0x4c3518) at do-rel.h:137
#2  _dl_relocate_object (scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=reloc_mode@entry=0, consider_profiling=<optimized out>) at dl-reloc.c:258
#3  0xb6fe2278 in dl_open_worker (a=0xb666cb60) at dl-open.c:377
#4  0xb6deb508 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=0xb666cbd8, operate=0xb6e20000, args=0xb666cb54) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#5  0xb6fe1c04 in _dl_open (file=0xb6f4cfcc "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=-2147483646, caller_dlopen=0xb6f4aebc <pthread_cancel_init+52>, 
    nsid=nsid@entry=-2, argc=2, argv=0xbefff654, env=0xbefff660) at dl-open.c:599
#6  0xb6dea880 in do_dlopen (ptr=0xb666cdcc) at dl-libc.c:96
#7  0xb6deb508 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=0x0, exception@entry=0xb666cd78, operate=0xb6e20000, args=0xb666cd78, 
    args@entry=0x152) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#8  0xb6deb5c8 in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0xb666cdac, objname@entry=0xb666cda4, errstring=0xb666cdb0, errstring@entry=0xb666cda8, 
    mallocedp=0xb666cdab, mallocedp@entry=0xb666cda3, operate=<optimized out>, args=0xb666cdcc, args@entry=0xb666cdc4)
    at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#9  0xb6dea9cc in dlerror_run (operate=<optimized out>, args=args@entry=0xb666cdc4) at dl-libc.c:46
#10 0xb6deaa70 in __GI___libc_dlopen_mode (name=<optimized out>, mode=mode@entry=-2147483646) at dl-libc.c:195
#11 0xb6f4aebc in pthread_cancel_init () at ../sysdeps/nptl/unwind-forcedunwind.c:53
#12 0xb6f4b080 in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (exc=0xb6f4b080 <_Unwind_ForcedUnwind+88>, stop=0x1, stop_argument=0xb666d6a8)
    at ../sysdeps/nptl/unwind-forcedunwind.c:127
#13 0xb6f48bb8 in __GI___pthread_unwind (buf=<optimized out>) at unwind.c:121
#14 0xb6f3f7f8 in __do_cancel () at pthreadP.h:304
#15 __pthread_exit (value=<optimized out>) at pthread_exit.c:28
#16 0x0022ecb4 in PyThread_exit_thread ()
#17 0x0020e868 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

*Note:* Solving the issue was to just install the missing library

`apt install libatlas3-base`
but as stated before I want to prevent the application from crashing should this problem arise. My application is capable of running with reduced functionality if `cv2` does not successfully import.

[Bug 20839](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20839) and [opencv-python/issues/381](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/381) sound like they may be related.

> "There are some cases in the implementation of dlopen where _dl_signal_error is called without removing all partially-initialized link maps.  The downstream bug report refers to an error raised from _dl_map_object in response to a missing file (the final call to _dl_signal_error).  We do some cleanup, but it seems we skip removal of a NODELETE object."

*Update*

I was able to prevent the Segfault even when `libcblas.so.3` is missing on the system by installing a different version of opencv with pip:
`opencv-python-headless`
. Seems like there may be some conflict with `opencv-python` and `PyQt5`.
This doesn't answer my question but will allow me to move on. I am still interested in an answer to the original question if anyone has one.

Comment: How do you create the second thread ?

Comment: ```t = threading.Thread(target=fn, daemon=True)``` You can see in the first code block above.

Comment: FWIW: i had a segfault backtrace that looks the same, but no missing libraries. I didn't get around to understand the issue, but fixed it by upgrading the docker base image from debian stretch (9) to bullseye (11).